# Weird stuff in server error log?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging, kill, pid

I have a PHP script that shuts down server processes based on their PIDs. It seems like it works well, however, I found this weird stuff in Apache's error log. Any idea on what it's saying?

```
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:09.609608 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 920] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:10.731370 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1548] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:10.731516 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1548] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:17.709118 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1548] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:33.913572 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 924] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:33.914387 2014] [core:notice] [pid 924] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

It doesn't even look like it's displaying any error, but it's in the error log anyways. Can someone explain what this is and if it's normal?

Answer (score 1):

These look like normal restart messages:

```
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:09.609608 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 920] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

is what you'd expect to see if the server is killed (probably by an init script), and

```
[Thu Jul 24 10:27:10.731370 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1548] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

is the first think you'll get in the logs as the server starts up.  Perhaps you restarted it yourself, or something like a log rotation script did it for you.

Comment: So does that mean everything is fine? Do I have anything to worry about? I have a PHP file using the `exec()` command killing these processes on my server by pid.

Comment: Apart from asking yourself why on earth you would want to do that, you have no additional worries :)

Comment: Ahh, well that's a relief. So why is it in the error log, is it just meant to be like that?

Comment: The error log is a bit of a misnomer: it contains anything Apache logs that isn't a request.